# Why "herzlich" in "herzlich wenig"?

Tags: etymology, phrase, meaning-in-context

Sometimes we hear the following expression in various contexts:

> Diese Antwort hat aber **herzlich wenig** mit meiner Frage zu tun.
>   Erwin hat **herzlich wenig** zum Erfolg unseres Projekts beigetragen.
>   Heute Nacht habe ich **herzlich wenig** geschlafen.

Why do we use *"herzlich"* here? Is there anything known on the etymology of this combination?

Comment: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/herzlich#Bedeutung2

Comment: @Em1 Takkat asks about the etymology of the expression.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I always thought (and still think) that it developed from an ironic/sarcastic remark, like

> Das interessiert mich herzlich wenig.

"Herzlich" is normally used for things/persons you are interested in. In the sentence above it is used in a contrary way to its original meaning and so giving the sentence a sarcastic touch.

Based on that usage people also used it to emphasize negative things ("herzlich wenig geschlafen"). If this explanation qualifies as "etymology" then here you go :)

Answer (score 1):

It is an idiom that originates from an irony joke.

The word simply acts as a filler like the English word "totally", at times.